# Combined view for Google, Apple and Exchange calendars in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, calendar

I am using Windows 8.1 and want to have the possibility to view (editing is not absolutely necessary) Calendars from an Google, Apple and Exchange account.

It's already working for me on my Android Phone which naturally supports Google Calendar and also syncs with Exchange out of the box. I'm using "SmoothSync" to integrate an iCloud Calendar.

I already tried rainlendar2 pro which can connect to these types of calendar, but the view is somehow too limited. I really would like to have something more like the outlook calendar view.